# Filling out specific cells with a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I've set up a tool able to issue release/return vouchers for equipment rental.

Command Button 1 enables you to create a release voucher and Command Button 2 a return voucher.

When clicking on number 2, you have to choose which Delivery Ticket (DT) is concerned by the return and indicate whether the equipment was used and when it came back.

How could I link the ticket number to the empty cells "used" and "date of return" from the corresponding line?

Through CommandButton2 you can select the right DT. After validating, I would like that the two cells mentioned above filled in the corresponding line.

Home Page picture with "Used" and "Date of Return" cells empty:

[image]

CommandButton2 `UserForm`:

[image]

This is the code for CommandButton1 and I would like to write something similar for #2 but without `List_order` since there's no `ListBox` in the second `UserForm`.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim part_serial As String

If Me.Cbx_serial.ListIndex >= 0 And Me.Txt_quantité <> "" Then

    With Me.List_order
        .AddItem
        .List(memoire, 0) = Me.Cbx_client
        .List(memoire, 1) = Me.Cbx_serial
        .List(memoire, 2) = Me.Txt_taille
        .List(memoire, 3) = Me.Txt_quantité
        .List(memoire, 4) = Me.Txt_well
        .List(memoire, 5) = Me.Txt_rig
        .List(memoire, 6) = Me.Txt_description
        .List(memoire, 7) = Me.Txt_note
    End With
    memoire = memoire + 1
    
    'empty boxes
    Me.Txt_well = ""
    Me.Txt_rig = ""
    Me.Cbx_serial = ""
    Me.Txt_quantité = ""
    Me.Txt_taille = ""
    Me.Txt_description = ""
    Me.Txt_note = ""
End If
End Sub

 
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim nombre_ligne As Integer
Dim ligne As Integer
Dim DL As Integer

If Me.List_order.ListCount > 0 And Me.Cbx_client.ListIndex >= 0 Then
    
    'ask for order confirmation
    If MsgBox("Voulez-vous valider le DT ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

        nombre_ligne = Me.List_order.ListCount - 1
    
        For ligne = 0 To nombre_ligne
            Sheets("DT").ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add
            DL = Sheets("DT").Range("b9999").End(xlUp).Row
        
            'display information in database order
            Sheets("DT").Range("A" & DL) = Me.List_order.List(ligne, 0)
            Sheets("DT").Range("B" & DL) = Me.List_order.List(ligne, 4)
            Sheets("DT").Range("C" & DL) = Me.List_order.List(ligne, 5)
            Sheets("DT").Range("D" & DL) = Me.List_order.List(ligne, 1)
            Sheets("DT").Range("E" & DL) = Me.List_order.List(ligne, 2)
            Sheets("DT").Range("F" & DL) = Me.List_order.List(ligne, 3)
            Sheets("DT").Range("G" & DL) = Me.List_order.List(ligne, 6)
            Sheets("DT").Range("I" & DL) = Label_info
            Sheets("DT").Range("J" & DL) = CDate(Now())
            Sheets("DT").Range("L" & DL) = Me.List_order.List(ligne, 7)
        Next ligne
    
        'Display PDF
    
        Sheets("DT Template").Range("C11") = Me.Label_info.Caption
    
        Sheets("DT Template").ExportAsFixedFormat _
          Type:=xlTypePDF, _
          Openafterpublish:=True
 
        Sheets("Config").Range("d24") = Sheets("Config").Range("d24") + 1
    
        Unload Add_dt_out
    
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "Validation impossible, select a supplier."

End If

End Sub
```